# How to restore a lost git mv?

Tags: git, github, merge

I am working on a long-running git branch, and early on in the history of the branch I renamed a file.

I subsequently merged changes from trunk back into my branch, which included changes to the file under its original name. After I had done this, while my local repo looked clean, when I looked at it in a Github PR it told me that there were merge conflicts - specifically that the file I had renamed had been removed, and that I could fix this with `git rm [original filename]` - so I did this and pushed the result, which now shows up as an empty merge commit.

Having done that, the history linking old and new files has now disappeared, and in the PR it shows an entirely new file under the new name, and a removed file under the old name.

I have tried reverting the "empty" merge commit, but when I do that and try to push it then nothing pushed, I'm told "Everything up-to-date".

How can I re-establish the link between the newly named file and the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple answers to this, most of which amount to "there is nothing to do here".

The first one is that you *can't* link these files.  Git does not track directories at all; it tracks only file contents.  Each commit is just a snapshot: in commit `1234567...`, there are some set of files, and here they are with their contents.  In another commit, `fedcba9...`, here is the set of files and their contents.

The second is that Git *discovers* file similarity on its own.  When you ask Git to tell you about some commit, Git looks at that commit and its parent commit.  The parent commit has a bunch of files as a snapshot.  The child—the commit you're asking Git about—has another bunch of files as a snapshot.  Git compares the two snapshots, and tells you what it finds different between them.  If one file seems to have gone missing, and another new file seems to have been created, well, perhaps that file was *renamed*.  Git checks!  If it finds two files that are exactly the same, but have different names in the two commits, well, the file must have been renamed.

If the file is gone from the parent and appears in the child and has *different* contents, it might still be renamed.  In this case, Git computes a *similarity index*.  If the files are "similar enough" (50% by default), Git assumes the file is renamed.

You have control, in some cases, over the similarity threshold.  When you ask Git to find renames for you, with `git diff -M`, you can specify the similarity threshold: `git diff -M75` means they must be at least 75% similar, while `git diff -M15` means they can be a mere 15% similar.

---

When you use `git merge`, git runs *two* `git diff` commands internally.  Both use `-M50%` and there is no control knob to let you change this.  If Git detects a renamed file in one of the two diffs, it makes a note of that.  If Git detects a different renaming, or another change to the *same* file, in the other of the two `git diff`s, you will get a modify/rename conflict, or a rename/delete conflict.  Note that the two diffs are from the *merge base*—a commit that Git finds for you automatically—to the two branch tip commits.  It's up to you to resolve any merge conflicts.

Eventually, you finish the merge by telling Git to commit some set of files—some new snapshot.  The snapshot you commit, based on what you left in the index, is what is in that commit.  If you remove a file from the index, it's not in the new commit.  If you keep the file, it is in the new commit.

The new commit you make has *two* parents.  One parent is the previous tip of the branch, just before you made this new commit that is now the tip of the branch.  The other parent commit is the commit you told Git to merge.

---

Whenever a commit you are having Git show is a merge commit, it has (at least) *two* parents.  Some Git commands do something special with this, and some just don't bother to show you a patch.  (Running `git log -p` in particular does the latter: shows you nothing at all.)  The merge is *not* empty!  The merge has a snapshot, just like any non-merge commit.  It's just that *comparing* the snapshot to both parents is tricky.  Some Git commands don't bother.  Others, like `git show`, do, but produce what Git calls a *combined diff*, which generally omits most or even all files from the diff output.

You can *split* the merge with `-m`, for display purposes.  Git will then compare each parent to the child, one at a time, and show you each individual diff.  One of these diffs will, presumably, remove one file.

If the merge you see is not the result you wanted, consider throwing the merge commit away (with `git reset`).  Note that this gets more difficult if you have `git push`ed the merge result elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!